Trouble understanding why adaline works
Recently came across adaline (an improvement on perceptron) but I am having trouble understanding why adaline works.
Lets take an example of 2D binary classification task. Assume line 'l' is a linear separation boundary for the same. Now, assume that the data points are in a such a way that most of the negative class points are concentrated very close to, but to the left of the line 'l' and the positive class has only 2 points (Point1 - very far from the line 'l' towards the right of it and Point2- very close to the line 'l' to the right of it). I feel that the way adaline's cost function is designed, the optimal line learned via adaline ('l*') will be slightly to the right of the Point1 thus misclassifying Point1. Can someone explain if this is the case or not or if I am missing something?
Overall, I am having trouble understanding why adaline works (since it penalizes for how far a point is from the separation line learned, which I feel should not be the case)
